# How do I use another field inside view as the base table?

Tags: 7, views

I would like to know how I may use a database field from a custom module to build queries on.

By default, using content view starts off querying from the "node" table. I would love to have the Views module to query from my own custom table.

I have tried using `hook_views_data()` and set a base table, but it all came to nought so far.

Answer (score 0):

Give this module a shot - [Views Expose Tables](https://drupal.org/project/views_expose_tables)

> Exposes Drupal DB tables to Views
>
> This is a simple module which does one thing: provides an admin page
>   for site-builders to choose which tables in a site's Drupal DB to
>   expose to Views.
>
> The module then loads all the fields for each chosen table and detects
>   the data type of the field and sets appropriate views field, sort,
>   filter, and argument filters (for example numeric, string, date, or
>   "default").
>
> It also looks for a primary key of the table and if one is found it
>   sets it as the base field for a views base table and makes the table
>   accessible to views.